# I want to identify duplicates and keep the most recent one and delete the other in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, duplicates, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I want duplicates in my data identified. Once I have this data I want to sort the duplicates by date and keep the most recent one.

I cannot not provide a copy of my sheet because of the sensitive information inside.

Comment: Welcome. The question is too broad as it doesn't include enough details. Regarding your sheet, create a demo sheet with fictitious data and also add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(B:B), 
 QUERY({A:B}, "select Col2,Col1 
               order by toDate(Col1) desc
               format Col1 'dd/mm/yyyy' ", 0), {2, 1}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(QUERY({Data!A:H}, 
 "select Col3
  where toDate(Col5) >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and toDate(Col5) <= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  order by toDate(Col1) desc ", 0)), 
 QUERY({Data!A:H}, 
 "select Col3,Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 
  where toDate(Col5) >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and toDate(Col5) <= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  order by toDate(Col1) desc
  format Col5 'mm/dd/yyyy' ", 0), {2,3,1,4,5,6,7}, 0)),
 "format Col1 'yyyy-nn-dd hh:mm:ss', Col5 'mm/dd/yyyy'"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(QUERY({Data!A:H}, 
 "select Col2
  where toDate(Col5) >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and toDate(Col5) <= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  order by toDate(Col1) desc ", 0)), 
 QUERY({Data!A:H}, 
 "select Col2,Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 
  where toDate(Col5) >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and toDate(Col5) <= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  order by toDate(Col1) desc
  format Col5 'mm/dd/yyyy' ", 0), {2,1,3,4,5,6,7}, 0)),
 "format Col1 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss', Col5 'mm/dd/yyyy'"))
```

Comment: The data is being pulled from the Data Sheet and being imported to Sheet2 and filtered out by the dates listed in row 1. The data that is being imported, I the duplicates removed but keeping the latest date. See the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: QUERY(All!A:Z, "select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H 
                 where toDate(E) >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
                   and toDate(E) <= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
                 order by (I) desc", (FILTER(A:Z,TRUE)
                  ))

Comment: what is the purpose of "(FILTER(A:Z,TRUE) " ?

Comment: The purpose of filter was to only show items that were not duplicates. This formula is only showing items that are duplicates.

Comment: @retter did you try the 2nd formula from the answer? if this still not what you seek, go to your sheet you shared and make manually an example of your expected outcome

Comment: The first formula returns no data. The 2nd formula only returns 7 results. It should return more. The only results that should not show up are the duplicated results. Everything that is not duplicated should be returned.

Comment: which column should be unique and with no duplicates? column with names Mike, Julie, etc. ??

Comment: Column B. The projects

Comment: Its showing more results but not all over them. Results should only be removed if there are duplicates. With duplicates the most recent date is kept. I added in green of what the results should be on the sheet.

Comment: it does exactly that but you probably forgot that you also filter by date range (A1, B1)  that's why you getting fewer results than you expect.

Comment: I see. So how do I make it return the results I want? Thanks for all of your help

Comment: widen the range... let A1 be 1/1/2000 and B1 be 1/1/2020 (for example)